# Nested List as DataProvider?

Tags: testng

Is there a relatively simple way to create a DataProvider method that feeds to a Test Method that takes List> or List as it's parameter? Our hybrid framework has the input data broken down into dynamic blocks, with only the number of inputs for a step held constant. I'm somewhat confused as to how to massage the method so that I can feed these into the Tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, are you just trying to pass lists to your test method? How about this:

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] dp() {
  return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3) },
      new Object[] { ImmutableList.of(4, 5) },
  }
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
public void test(List<Integer> l) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Well, it's more like I'm trying to return list of lists/arrays, but the main issue I'm not too sure how to format the data to fit testNG's format. For example, I have method that returns a list of data blocks:
 
`@DataProvider (name = "LoginData")
 public Iterator<List<String[]>> LoginTestData()
 {
  List<List<String[]>> temp = dataProviderHelper(DataPath, DataID);
  return temp.iterator(); 
 }`

What changes do I need to make for it to work correctly?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out from your example. Have to explicitly declare return type as Iterator<Object[]> and also transfer the list into the Object container. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think I have a related problem when using dataProviders in such a way. Namely, that on the testNG/report output, it lists the Class Name with bunch of gibberish (well not really gibberish, but the names of the string arrays ) as the parameters of the test. For example, one passed run of gave this as output:
'PASSED: MN01NodeMgmtTest([[Ljava.lang.String;@577dc2ae, [Ljava.lang.String;@1785a62, [Ljava.lang.String;@475d8af, [Ljava.lang.String;@54e4cb72, [Ljava.lang.String;@78e8d4e8, [Ljava.lang.String;@7df2095b])'
 Is there some way I can replace this with more meaningful text?